# Is it true that $(\int f)^2 \le \int f^2$, $e^{\int f} \le \int e^f$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, integral-inequality

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space. Suppose $\mu(X) = 1$, and let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue integrable. Are the following inequalities true or not?

$$(\int f)^2 \le \int f^2$$
  $$e^{\int f} \le \int e^f$$

Comment: I'm confused: is $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ an arbitrary measure space, or are we using only the Lebesgue integral, and $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Do you mean $\left(\int_Xf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^2\le\int_Xf(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x$ and $e^{\int_Xf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}\le\int_Xe^{f(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x$?

Answer (score 1):

These follow from [Jensen's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) and the fact that $x^2$ and $e^x$ are [convex functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function).

Comment: I don't follow? Is it possible you could elaborate a bit?

Comment: Did you look up Jensen's Inequality using the link provided? Are you having problems applying it? Do you know what a convex function is? I have added a link to convex functions as well.